# Getting trouble with netbeans SVN plugin

Tags: svn, version-control, netbeans-7

I'm using uber SVN and Netbeans7.x in my project development.I've kept my actual project in SVN and checking out using Netbeans,my local copy is getting synchronized with the SVN copy.The problem is when I create a new project in my local system it is also get synchronizing with SVN.How can I overcome this issue ?

Thanks